# Getting current Git branch name using dulwich library

Tags: python, git, branch, dulwich

I am trying to get the name of the current branch of a Git repository using the [dulwich](https://www.dulwich.io/) library. I have spent lots of time looking through dulwich's documentation but could not find out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final result, which removes the initial refs/heads/ prefix:

```
>>> from dulwich.repo import Repo
>>> import re
>>> repo = Repo('.')
>>> (_, ref), _ = repo.refs.follow(b'HEAD')
>>> match = re.search(r'/([^/]+)$', ref.decode('utf-8')
>>> match[1]
'master'
```

Comment: Note that in theory, the length of the refchain can be something other than 2. If you have a detached HEAD, the refchain will be [b"HEAD"]. If the master branch is a symref to another branch (not common, but possible) then the refchain may be longer than 2 entries.

Comment: So do I just put a star in front of the 2nd underscore (`(_, ref), *_ = `) to avoid this issue?

Comment: The returned tuple always has two elements: a refchain and the commit SHA. The refchain is a list that can have between 1 and many elements, not necessarily two. This is why my example above used ref_chain[1].

Comment: oh. so i will just use your example and replace `commit_sha` with `_`

Answer (score 2):

The active branch is whatever branch "HEAD" currently points at. You can get that ref in Dulwich using something like this:

```
 >>> from dulwich.repo import Repo
 >>> x = Repo('.')
 >>> ref_chain, commit_sha = x.refs.follow(b'HEAD')
 >>> ref_chain[1]
 b'refs/heads/master'
```

There is now also a `dulwich.porcelain.active_branch` function in master that can do this for you.

Comment: Thanks. I chose to do `(_, ref), _ = x.refs.follow(b'HEAD')`

Comment: I have another question about Dulwich: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58781823/11041613