# How to get URL of remote in Dulwich

Tags: python, dulwich

I want to be able to get a URL like `https://github.com/user/repo.git` given a remote name such as `origin`. So far I have only managed to get the commit hash:

```
>>> from dulwich import porcelain
>>> hash = porcelain.ls_remote('.')[b'refs/remotes/origin/master']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, there is no porcelain wrapper for this. With the plumbing, you can use:

```
>>> from dulwich.repo import Repo
>>> config = Repo('.').get_config()
>>> config.get(('remote', 'origin'), 'url')
b'git://jelmer.uk/dulwich'
```